# how to start animation using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am converting my exising Application using WPF and MVVM pattern.
I have different storyboards in my view .

eg. 1. showing splashscreen while loading the app
       2. while clicking Menu Toggle button/Radio Button to show the slide in and Slide out animation effect
       3. And different mouseover effect for different elements available in the View.

How will i call the storyboard using MVVM and which is the best method?. To show the mouse over effect do we really have to use MVVM or code behind?

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, I'm not sure your requirements, or the best way to do this, but one idea is you can use code similar to #3 below, but replace  `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">` with   `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">`

To answer question 2, Here is how I begin a storyboard when a user changes a radio button. This is all in XAML:

```
<CheckBox Content="Radio Button Option 1" >
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
               <im:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource NameOfStoryboardToRunOnCheck}"/>
          </i:EventTrigger>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
               <im:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource NameOfStoryboardToRunOnUnCheck}"/>
          </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

For Question 3, here is an example of OnMouseOver

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
          <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverStoryboard}" />
     </EventTrigger>
     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
          <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeaveStoryboard}" />
     </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```